# Hacer un alert con php tras un formulario

Tags: javascript, php

soy novato en la programación, hace poco hice una "aplicacion" la cual guarda unos datos en un input a una tabla en mysql y los muestra en la pagina en forma de tabla, por un form

```
<form action="enviar.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <p><b>Fecha de Origen<br/><input type="text" name="FechaO" placeholder="Escriba la Fecha" required></input></b></p>
        <p><b>Materia<br/><input type="text" name="materia" placeholder="Escriba la Materia" required></input></b></p>
        <p><b>Descripcion<br/><input type="text" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Escriba la Descripcion" required></input></b></p>
        <p><b>Fecha de Entrega<br/><input type="text" name="FechaE" placeholder="Escriba la Fecha" required></input></b></p>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
<?php
header("Location: Formulario.php");
include("php.php");
        if($_POST){
  $fecha1 = $_POST['FechaO'];
  $materia = $_POST['materia'];
  $descripcion = $_POST['Descripcion'];
  $fecha2 = $_POST['FechaE'];
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO tareas_t(Fecha_de_Origen,Materia,Descripcion,Fecha_de_Entrega)values('$fecha1','$materia','$descripcion','$fecha2')") or die(mysql_error());
 }

    ?>
```

pero al darle en el boton de enviar, este me redireccionaba a la pagina, entonces puse header("Location: formulario.php"), y me trabaja a la perfeccion pero quiero que al darle enviar y se envien los datos a la tabla de mysql, este me muestre un alert diciendo Tarea guardada, gracias por la ayuda y la atencion prestada.

Comment: Puedes mostrar un Alert desde php  así : `echo "<script>alert('Tarea guardada')</script>";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

puedes hacer lo siguiente.

```
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Tarea Guardada");
    window.location.href="index.php";
    </script>';
```

lo pones al termino de tu `insert`.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tareas_t(Fecha_de_Origen,Materia,Descripcion,Fecha_de_Entrega)values('$fecha1','$materia','$descripcion','$fecha2')") or die(mysql_error());

echo'<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("Tarea Guardada");
        window.location.href="index.php";
        </script>';
```

Comment: Pregunta, quise utilizar esta solución pero no me valida los campos con el atributo "required", cómo puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Es una posibilidad utilizar algo mas o menos interactivo como javascript, no es difícil de implementar, realmente hace años que no toco php, pero creo que el siguiente código te puede servir, sólo que tenés que configurar la ruta bien del archivo .js en las tags header. Creo que en php funciona tmb. si no llegase a funcionar lo único que habría que hacer es modificar el type="submit" por "button".

```
<html>



<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="path donde estaría tu archivo ejemplo: /src/javascript.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>

<form action="enviar.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <p><b>Fecha de Origen<br/><input type="text" name="FechaO" placeholder="Escriba la Fecha" required></input></b></p>
    <p><b>Materia<br/><input type="text" name="materia" placeholder="Escriba la Materia" required></input></b></p>
    <p><b>Descripcion<br/><input type="text" name="Descripcion" placeholder="Escriba la Descripcion" required></input></b></p>
    <p><b>Fecha de Entrega<br/><input type="text" name="FechaE" placeholder="Escriba la Fecha" required></input></b></p>
    <input type="submit" onclick="funcionAlerta()"/>
    </form>
<?php
header("Location: Formulario.php");
include("php.php");
    if($_POST){
  $fecha1 = $_POST['FechaO'];
  $materia = $_POST['materia'];
  $descripcion = $_POST['Descripcion'];
  $fecha2 = $_POST['FechaE'];
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO  tareas_t(Fecha_de_Origen,Materia,Descripcion,Fecha_de_Entrega)values('$fecha1','$materia','$descripcion','$fecha2')") or die(mysql_error());
 }

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Y en el archivo javascript.js creas una función masomenos así:

```
function funcionAlerta(){
alert("Los datos han sido enviados o lo que quieras");
}
```